# Oracle DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT initialization vector length for AES256

Tags: java, sql, encryption, plsql, aes

Is there a minimum/max length for the initialization vector when using the DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT proc?  I get the error below:

```
ORA-28817: PL/SQL function returned an error.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO_FFI", line 3
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO", line 13
ORA-06512: at "Test_Encryption", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

The code generating this error is as follows:

```
raw_encrypted_token := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT( src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW( input_token, 'AL32UTF8' ),
                                            typ => encryption_type,
                                            key => key_raw_form,
                                            iv => hextoraw('0123456789ABCDEF') );
```

When I change the key from 16 to 32 bytes I have no issues.  However, I am experimenting decoding in Java using the Cipher object and the initialization vector can only be 16 bytes long.  Any suggestions as to how I can solve the initialization vector issue in the pl/sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most block cipher modes of operation the initialization vector should have the same length as the block size. For AES, this is 128 bit = 16 bytes.

Your code

```
hextoraw('0123456789ABCDEF')
```

actually produces a 16·4=64-bit value, since each hexadecimal digit corresponds to 4 bits, not to an 8 bit byte.
So a 32 hex-digit string is the right length for a 128-bit initialization vector.

On another note, you should not use an hard-coded initialization vector if you use the same key for each record. For security purposes, each record should be encrypted with its own initialization vector - preferable a random one, though depending on the mode of operation (i.e. CTR), a unique one could be enough (if you let some space between consecutive ones).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I no longer get the error above.  However, I am getting the following when I try to decrypt in Java:

`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`

Comment: This could mean that you are using a different padding type, a different mode of operation, a different key or different initialization vector. Without more details, there is no way of deciding this.